# How to get the half part of forloop in django template

Tags: python, html, django

I want to sperate the half part of forloop in another column,
like this:http://demo.webdeveloperplus.com/drag-drop-panels/
Now, I wrote it using django template,
However I have no idea to separate the half into column2?

Below is what I loop all line in column1

```
<div class="column" id="column1">
<ul>
{% for line in lines %}
        <li>{{ line.node }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</div>
```

what I want are:

```
<div class="column" id="column1">
half nodes
</div>

<div class="column" id="column2">
the another half nodes
</div>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make two context variables in your view:

```
offset = len(lines) / 2

if offset % 2 != 0:
    # ensure that the second col does not contain more than the first one
    offset += 1

lines_col0 = lines[:offset]
lines_col1 = lines[offset:]
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it,I can filter them in views.py.

Comment: NP, please close the question :)

Comment: No need to close the question. He should post his own answer!