# Django template. I want to display one views query into two columns

Tags: html, django, django-queryset

I want to display one query into two coulmns for explain: I have 22 elements in my query and i want to display it as 11 on the left and 11 on the right.

```
    <div class="list-group container">


    <div class="list-group-item">
        {% for k in kategoria %}
<div class="media align-items-center">
    <div class="mr-3">


    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
     <a href="{% url 'katalog:kategoria' pk=k.pk %}">
        <h5 class="text-md d-block text-limit mb-2 ml-5 text-left"><u>{{k.name}}</u></h5>

    </div>
    <div class="media-body">
      <a href="{% url 'katalog:kategoria' pk=k.pk %}">
         <h5 class="text-md d-block text-limit mb-2 ml-5 text-left"><u>{{k.name}}</u></h5>

     </div>

</div>
{% endfor %}
    </div>




</div>
```

This is my code, actually my website looks like:

[image: My website]

I just want to display half of the list on the left and the second half on the right.

Comment: If you put the data in an unordered list `<ul>` you can apply columns styling in CSS with `ul { columns: 2; }`

Comment: check if this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9454067/13168118 solves your issue, by handling the dividing into two lists in the view and then show list_one on the left and list_two on the right

Comment: im not familiar with django tempate.
but the idea is to nest your left <div> in IF statement.

if the template support typical for loop like this => var i; i<total.count; i++. (if not, i bet at least you can assign variable for counting? and just do var++)

then use remainder (%2) to check if ODD or EVEN.

then just echo 1st div if iteration == odd, else echo 2nd div.

this should make your Odd number list in left side, Even in right side.